# Converting csv string into Map with double quoted keys/values

Tags: java, csv, collections, jackson

I'm working on converting `CSV` string to `Map`. I'm able to convert it but the issue is I need to get the keys and values in Map with double quotes`""`

> input string: "fname", "lname", ...... \n 
>   "ramprakash","seepana",...
>
> Getting data [fname=ramprakash, lname=seepana, ...]
>
> Expected data is: ["fname"="ramprakash", "lname"="seepana", ...]

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide your trial code as described in [mcve]. Also some CSV input sample would be helpful.

Comment: Could you provide example `CSV` you are trying to read?

Comment: @michal Added input CSV string

Answer (score 1):

Assume your `CSV` looks like below:

```
"fname", "lname"
"ramprakash","seepana"
"ramprakash1","seepana1"
```

To have `"` you need to disable in `CsvSchema` quote char. Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File csv = new File("./resource/test.csv").getAbsoluteFile();

        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();

        CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema
                .emptySchema()
                .withHeader()
                .withColumnSeparator(',')
                .withoutQuoteChar();

        MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> it = mapper
                .readerFor(Map.class)
                .with(schema)
                .readValues(csv);


        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"fname"="ramprakash", "lname"="seepana"}
{"fname"="ramprakash1", "lname"="seepana1"}
```

Comment: I like your explanation in steps: (1) given you have (2) when you solve like this (3) then you get. Besides: _FasterXML_ / _Jackson_ object-mapping API is mature and used by other frameworks like _Spring_. So it's a good invest.

Answer (score 0):

For processing CSV [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial) is your best bet. It's also [faster](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) than any other parser.

Try this code:

```
String input = "'fname','lname'\n'ramprakash','seepana'\n";

CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial
settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //use first row as headers
settings.getFormat().setQuote('\''); //using single quotes for clarity

settings.setKeepQuotes(true); //keep the quotes

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
for (Record record : parser.iterateRecords(new StringReader(input))) {
    Map<String, String> map = record.toFieldMap();
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Output:

```
{fname='ramprakash', lname='seepana'}
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:

I just noticed headers won't be enclosed in quotes (typically it's what people want). You can still get everything with quotes as plain rows and fill a map yourself:

```
    String input = "'fname','lname'\n'ramprakash','seepana'\n'I won\\'t go away'";

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setQuote('\'');
    settings.getFormat().setQuoteEscape('\\'); //added escape quote character too

    settings.setKeepQuotes(true);
    settings.setKeepEscapeSequences(true); //you probably want this

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    for (String[] row: parser.iterate(new StringReader(input))) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
```

That prints:

```
['fname', 'lname']
['ramprakash', 'seepana']
['I won\'t go away']
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license)